# bluebird 'forgotten returns' warning in AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, bluebird, asyncstorage

I am considering using the `bluebird` promises library in a ReactNative app, but it issues some warnings that are difficult to track down and debug. The warnings I am getting are:

```
Warning: a Promise was created in a handler at internal/process/task_queue.js:75:11 but was not returned from it
```

Unfortunately there is no proper stacktrace given, but by using the debugger, inspecting the AppBundle and grepping for similar code, I think I tracked it down to this method in AsyncStorage.js:

```
getItem: function(
  key: string,
  callback?: ?(error: ?Error, result: ?string) => void,
): Promise {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    RCTAsyncStorage.multiGet([key], function(errors, result) {
      // Unpack result to get value from [[key,value]]
      const value = result && result[0] && result[0][1] ? result[0][1] : null;
      const errs = convertErrors(errors);
      callback && callback(errs && errs[0], value);
      if (errs) {
        reject(errs[0]);
      } else {
        resolve(value);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Is this method problematic, or did I fail to find the source of the problem? If it is problematic, what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: Why does your function take a callback when it already returns a promise? If necessary for backward compatibility, you should at least [let Bluebird do the call for you](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/ascallback.html).

Comment: Are you passing a callback to `getItem`? And how is `RCTAsyncStorage.multiGet` implemented, does it create a promise (that is then unused) as well?